# Using a textbox entry to filter a datagridview with an int value? VS C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview, filter

I'm using a datagridview to display data, and this code to search/filter it using a text box.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       try
       {

           BindingSource bs_sp = new BindingSource();

           bs_sp.DataSource = senior_playersDataGridView.DataSource;

           bs_sp.Filter = "first_name like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";

           senior_playersDataGridView.DataSource = bs_sp;
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Search failed");  
       }
   }
```

This successfully searches/filters the database by a forename the user enters, which is a string.

However if I want to search/filter a column that uses an int datatype, obviously the like statement no longer works, as this only applies to strings.

How do I modify this to get it to take a number input into the textbox, and search the grid by that int value?

Comment: [From here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62325081-0d57-45d1-954f-b5d78e1ca035/using-the-bindingsource-filter-property-for-integer-column?forum=csharpgeneral): `bs.Filter = "CONVERT(dat, 'System.String') LIKE '98%'";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use convert.

```
bs_sp.Filter = "Convert(age, 'System.String') like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
```